# Remove specific tabs in from WooCommerce admin settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, settings, hook-woocommerce

I would like specific users to only see the WooCommerce -> Settings -> Shipping menu. I've managed to remove other tabs e.g. Products, Payments, etc, but stuck on the following 2 things that I want to accomplish:

1. Remove the "GENERAL" tab in WooCommerce Settings.
2. Remove the "ORDER STATUSES" Tab from a plugin. (Note: this isn't a tab exactly, the slug is
   'edit.php?post_type=wc_order_status')

[image]

When I try to remove the GENERAL tab, it eliminates the entire Settings menu. As for the 'Order Statuses', my code just doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'remove_woocommerce_setting_tabs', 200, 1 );
function remove_woocommerce_setting_tabs( $array ) {

    global $current_user;

    //Declare the tabs we want to hide
    $tabs_to_hide = array(
        'general'         => 'General', //this one removes the entire Settings menu
        'wc_order_status' => 'Order Statuses'// this doesn't work, maybe bc it's a post_type
        );

    // Remove tab if user role is shipping_manager
    if ( in_array("shipping_manager", $$current_user->roles) ) {
        $array = array_diff_key($array, $tabs_to_hide);
    }
}
```

I had also tried the below code to remove the ORDER STATUSES tab, but still no luck:

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_order_statuses_tab', 999);
    function remove_order_statuses_tab() 
    {
      global $current_user;

      if ( in_array("shipping_manager", $current_user->roles) ) {
            remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=wc_order_status' ); //not working either
         }

    }
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay. So it didn't work all the way, and wasn't sure whether to mark it as an answer for the whole question. Responding now to all the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct hook to be used is `woocommerce_settings_tabs_array`.

First you need to find which are the **array keys** that you need to remove from the tabs array in your code.

For that you will use first the following function that will display all array data in Admin WooCommerce settings *(only for testing, to be removed)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'filter_wc_settings_tabs_array', 990, 1 );
function filter_wc_settings_tabs_array( $tabs_array ) {
    // Display raw array data
    echo '<pre>'; print_r( $tabs_array ); echo '</pre>';

    return $tabs_array;
}
```

It will display something like *(with all required array keys)*:

[image]

Now you can get the array keys slugs that you need, to remove the corresponding tab settings. So now **you will be able to find the correct array key slug** for you Third party plugin WooCommerce setting tab, that you will use in the function code below.

**To target a specific user role**, you can either use global $current_user; $current_user->roles; or the Wordpress dedicated function [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)…

So the working code that will remove specific setting tabs for a user role is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'filter_wc_settings_tabs_array', 200, 1 );
function filter_wc_settings_tabs_array( $tabs_array ) {
    // Only for "shipping_manager" user role
    if( current_user_can( 'shipping_manager' ) ) {
        // Remove some specific tabs
        unset( $tabs_array['general'], $tabs_array['order_status'] ); // <== replace 'order_status' by 
    }

    return $tabs_array;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: This worked for removing the standard WC tabs. However, I wasn't able to remove the tab that came with the plugin, even after I used the JS proposed.

Comment: @Les Before the `return $tabs_array;` try to include `echo '<div><pre>'; print_r( $tabs_array ); echo '</pre></div>';` just to get all usable array keys, to find out the right key you need. Once you get it remove it and make the necessary changes in the code.

Comment: It only prints the names of the standard WC tabs only, but not the tab from the custom plugin. I'm thinking it is not considered a tab in the strict sense. When I hover or click on the standard WC tabs, I'll see the url showing as `wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings` (in the example of Settings tab). However, on the custom plugin tab, it shows as `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wc_order_status`

Comment: @Les You should try to go in the plugin source code to find out how they display their custom tabs in WooCommerce settings…

Comment: Got this to work, but the custom tab had to be hidden with jQuery as shown in the answer below.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'remove_woocommerce_setting_tabs', 200, 1 );

function remove_woocommerce_setting_tabs( $array ) {

        global $current_user;

        // Remove tab if user role is shipping_manager

        if ( in_array( "shipping_manager", $current_user->roles ) ) {
            unset( $array[ 'general' ] );
            ?>
                <script>
            document.querySelector("[href='<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=wc_order_status' ) ); ?>']").style.display = 'none';

            </script>
        <?php
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Try this code snippet

Comment: This didn't work, same effect that I have. When I remove the "general" tab, the entire settings menu. The wc_order_status is not really a tab such as the general one, which points to: admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=general. Rather, the url is displayed as: wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wc_order_status

Comment: @Les if you comment out this line - unset( $array[ 'wc_order_status' ] ); - it will work. I thought that's a custom tab you have added. This code is tested ok with WP 5.4 and WC 4.0.1

Comment: Still no luck. Could it be something to do with the user role? The Order Statuses settings is a 3rd party plugin that is accessed as follows: 'edit.php?post_type=wc_order_status'. Unlike the other tabs that are accessed as 'admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping' for example. Know how you can eliminate that tab?

Comment: @Les Which plugin.?

Comment: Plugin is called "WooCommerce Order Status Manager"

Comment: Its added by the plugin , -   // add Order Statuses tab to settings
  add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs', array( $this, 'print_settings_tabs'), 1 );  Line 90 - /plugins/woocommerce-order-status-manager/includes/admin/class-wc-order-status-manager-admin.php

Comment: Yes, but still no lick. I also tested using both Administrator and Shop Manager but still no luck

Comment: Finally got this working by moving the jQuery to this hook: `add_action( 'admin_footer', 'hide_order_status_js' )`